# Read, and use, substrings from witihin lines of a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to make a batch file, which when I start it, will say the number that is in it.

I am making a text adventure game and I would like a load and save feature. I already have it set up, so it saves the data, and puts it in a `.txt` file.

ex:

> ```
> Health:85
> Armor:10
> coin:5
> ```

So I would like it to see the data, and use it.

Here is my code:

```
:save
echo health=%health% >> FCSAV.txt
echo exp=%exp% >> FCSAV.txt
echo coin=%coin% >> FCSAV.txt
echo playerdmg=%playerdmg% >> FCSAV.txt
echo gender=%gender% >> FCSAV.txt
echo role=%role% >> FCSAV.txt
echo armor=%armor% >> FCSAV.txt
echo temp1=%temp1% >> FCSAV.txt
exit
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export batch variables to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008693/export-batch-variables-to-text-file) Specifically MC ND's answer where you `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("FCSAV.txt") do set %%a`

Comment: Similarly, you could use the methodology I offered recently, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65923627). Please in future use the search facility before posting questions, especially as it is clear that your task has been sked about, and answwered before.

Comment: Thx for all the comments this helped me alot!